# Global data from eloquent in Laravel to be used for layout

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am using some variables in the layout which will load data from the eloquent. For this purpose I am using repository pattern which are injected into the controller through constructor. But obviously, I don't want to repeat this logic in every controller I make.

What is the best approach to solve this?

I have tried injecting the repositories into the BaseController constructor, but the baseController constructor is not getting called automatically. I need to call for parent::__construct() first which requires repositories parameters to be passed. Which I believe is not the correct way to do this.

This is my BaseController.

```
    class BaseController extends Controller {

    /**
     * Setup the layout used by the controller.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected $repo;

    public function __construct(Repository $repo) {

        $this->repo = $repo;
    }


    protected function setupLayout()
    {
        if ( ! is_null($this->layout))
        {
            $this->layout = View::make($this->layout);
        }

        $data = $this->repo->someMethod();

        View::share('global_data',$data);
    }

 }
```

BaseController constructor is not called automatically to resolve the dependencies.

What is the best approach to have global data from repositories to be used in the layout?

Comment: You should look into [View Composers](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/views#view-composers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To call the BaseController you can put `parent::__construct()` in the constructor of that controller. If you have any legacy code that you need to support, this might be the fastest way to get up and running.

Going forward there are [View Composers](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/views#view-composers) that you can set up to set up a service to listen for that variable to be requested in a view and then lazy load it as needed. The performance implementation of this is usually negligible but is only called when the view is rendered so it cannot call back into the framework if needed.

You can also use a [route filter](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing) (in L4) for the like controllers that need that param or [middleware](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/middleware) (in L5) but this is only if you have more work that needs to get done than just a variable/value and should be done before the controller is even loaded.